# Regular expression to trim from a line, get the number in the line

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

Need to get the total memory info from the unix system from proc mem info:
right now this command gets the right line for me:
`cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemTotal"` 
But this returns the whole line:

```
MemTotal:      1024984 kB
```

I need to trim that line even further into:

`1024984 kB`

So far this is the full command I am using but the second part doesn't seem to work:

`cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemTotal" | grep -E -o "([0-9])"`

I thought that the second grep would at least return the numeric part, however its not returning anything at all.

Can anyone help me correct this?
Thanks.

Comment: `(\d+)+.*` you can try this one, but also here is usefull tool to test your regular expressions [link](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: `grep -Eo '[0-9]+'` to get numeric part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` is better suited here, for all lines matching `MemTotal`, print the 2nd and 3rd column

```
$ grep 'MemTotal' /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1024984 kB
$ awk '/MemTotal/{print $2,$3}' /proc/meminfo
1024984 kB
```

With `grep`, if PCRE is available use variable-length lookbehind:

```
$ grep -oP 'MemTotal:\h+\K.*' /proc/meminfo
1024984 kB
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird, for me, it returns

```
8
0
8
4
9
0
4
```

That's because `[0-9]` only matches *one* digit. You need a `+` to match *at least one*. You can also drop the parentheses, they serve no purpose here.

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | grep -E -o '[0-9]+'
```